# Inconsistency with $filter /messages on Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have encountered an odd issue (inconsistency) which seems to be related to the $filter capability of the fetch messages endpoint on Graph.

We reply on querying for messages by their internetMessageId field.
This normally works, but in some cases we’ve seen that the result set is empty (no error), and the odd thing is the same message can be fetched by its subject or sender’s address.

**This API call returns an empty result:**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_principal_name>/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<CAPJZXvF23=Ut7ksuJzCV+dQa6Pjy+3+uRU7j0v-GLydAi974Rg@mail.gmail.com>'`

**This API call works:**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_principal_name>/messages?$filter=sender/emailAddress/address eq '<sender_address>'`

Answer (score 1):

We looked into this, and the problem here is with the app behavior, not the service.
Both queries work as expected, provided that the URL query parameters are correctly encoded by the app, per HTTP encoding practices.

In the first request, there are `+` characters in the `internetMessageId` value that the app does not encode before sending the request; the service decodes them into spaces, and that is why the query returns empty results.

When the query string is properly, the correct results are returned, as expected.

We recommend apps always encode the request URL.